# How to make really bad results from a machine learning model better by reversing predictions

Tags: classification, roc, accuracy, auc, false-positive-rate

I trained a classification model on some data with two classes and have really low accuracy. I have a false-positive rate of 86 % for both classes I am trying to predict. I was wondering if I could get a good Classifier in the following way (described in pseudocode, where x is a data point and Classifier(x) is my bad classifier applied to x.)

```
    for a point x:
        if Classifier(x) gives Class 1
            return Class 2.
        else Classifier(x) gives Class 2
            return Class 1.
```

Basically, I would ask a new classifier to choose the opposite of whatever my bad classifier chose. Is this valid? Am I right in thinking that I will get a 86 % true positive rate for both classes? I would love any intuition on the creation of such a classifier.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are the frequencies of the two classes in your data set?

Comment: The frequencies should be 50/50

Comment: Are you sure you're interpreting the output correctly?  Randomly choosing the class with a 50% probability of choosing each class would generate a 50% false positive rate on average, as would just picking one of the two classes all the time - hard to see how a model would do far worse than that.

Answer (score 1):

This reminds me of a quote in a show I like called *Scrubs*. The jerk professor is teaching a young MD and asks her to decide between two treatment plans. She gives her thoughts, and the professor goes with the other treatment plan. "You're usually wrong, so if I'm ever in doubt, I just go the opposite direction as you," he tells her.

Yes, if you have a misclassification rate of $86\%$ and you reverse every one of the binary predictions, you will wind up with $86\%$ accuracy. Perhaps it is easiest to see why this is true by taking it to the extreme: if your model predicts every dog as a cat and every cat as a dog, then you get perfect accuracy by predicting dog when the model says cat and predicting cat when the model says dog.

I would want to investigate this further to see what has gone wrong and if it is reasonable to be able to count on the model classifications to be reliably bad so that reversing the predictions will be reliably good, however.